# How to properly and simply profile a function in scala?

Tags: performance, scala, profiling, sbt, jmh

I am trying to reverse a string containing unicode characters in Scala.
I want to find the fastest way to do it. 
So far I have this code:

```
import scala.runtime.RichChar

def reverseInPlace(s: String): String = {
   val reverse = new Array[RichChar](s.length)   
   for (i <- (0 to (s.length >> 1))) {
     reverse(i) = s(s.length -i -1)
     reverse(s.length -i -1) = s(i)
   }
   return reverse.mkString
}

def reverseLeft(s: String): String = s.foldLeft("") ( (a,b) => 
    b + a
)

def reverseRight(s: String): String = s.foldRight("") ( (a,b) => 
    b + a
)


def time[R](iterations:Int, block: => R) = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    for ( i <- 0 to iterations){
       block    // call-by-name
    }
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
}


time(1000, {
    reverseRight("Hello\u0041")
})

time(1000, {
    reverseInPlace("Hello\u0041")
})

time(1000, {
    reverseLeft("Hello\u0041")
})

time(1000, {
    "Hello\u0041".reverse
})
```

and on my macbook 2013 I get these results:

```
Elapsed time: 37013000ns
Elapsed time: 23592000ns
Elapsed time: 11647000ns
Elapsed time: 5579000ns
```

But I feel those numbers are bogus numbers.
Who do I properly benchmark the functions using scala, sbt and the JMH library ?

Note: As pointed out from the comments, micro benchmarking in Java is a serious business
See ([How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/2390083)) and https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mechanical-sympathy/m4opvy4xq3U/7lY8x8SvHgwJ. For why you shouldn't try to microbenchmark without using an external library.

Comment: If you do not want to use an external library, your question is effectively a duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/2390083). If you accept an external library, consider [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: BTW as for `reverseInPlace`: Consider rewriting it to using `while` instead of `for` (which is a for comprehension which is syntactic sugar for Scala library functions).

Comment: Yet another BTW: Looking at your source, it doesn't seem to be too bogus: `foldRight` is implemented as `reverse + foldLeft`. Your InPlace functions does not use `while`. `foldLeft` uses `while` and head/tail traversal. `StringOps.reverse` uses a builder with a size hint. So your numbers *could* be valid, but that should be checked with JMH etc.

Comment: Why don't you use an external library?  If you don't like the heavyweight alternatives, I wrote a lightweight one for cases just like this: https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme and you can probably find others (e.g. the `scala.testing.Benchmark` trait).

Comment: Incidentally, none of your solutions properly handle multi-UTF16 code points.  (Neither does the `reverse` method, though.)

Comment: @Beryllium as an important side note, even though Caliper is mentioned in that question and it is an established industry standard tool, [it is criticized by some of the Oracle (guys behind java and jvm) engineers](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mechanical-sympathy/m4opvy4xq3U/7lY8x8SvHgwJ). And yes, JMH is the prefered alternative.

Comment: @Beryllium Okay how would you use JMH In scala with sbt to actually benchmark it ? From the instructions look like you have to write a bunch of java code and use maven ... ?

Comment: @RexKerr How would you make it so that handles all the utfs ?

Comment: @fabrizioM As for the combination of sbt + JMH ... I gave up some days ago. I had even prepared a question for SO, but decided to stick with maven, as that's the way it is documented. JMH is not just a simple library, it is deeply integrated as a maven plugin. So for normal Scala projects I use sbt. If it's benchmarking time, I use JMH. As for your case, it would be very simple (I am in no way a maven expert). So if you accept maven, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @fabrizioM: You don't need to write Java code to use Scala benchmarks with JMH. Follow the instructions on JMH page (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to bootstrap the Scala benchmark project. Yes, the "quickest" way uses Maven.

Comment: @Beryllium: "JMH is [...] deeply integrated as a maven plugin." -- it does not. You can use it without Maven involved, e.g. with Gradle (http://gvsmirnov.ru/blog/tech/2014/03/10/keeping-your-benchmarks-separate.html), or Ant (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-ant-sample/). SBT integration is on Scala guys ;)

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev Well, yes, I know, I have tried it some hours based on those ant/gradle approaches. What I meant by "deeply integrated" is anything more than adding a dependency or plugin (in terms of sbt). It does not mean "hardcoded/monolithic". Give me some time, I'm going to post my sbt/JMH attempts in a separate question.

Comment: @Beryllium: OK. Because Jamie Allen (TypeSafe) was planning to get SBT support for JMH, and we discussed a few options. I think jmh-dev@ is a better alias to discuss this, since the narrow-scoped integration questions seem out of scope for SO?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using not *no* framework, but Thyme which I wrote because I wanted a microbenchmarking framework to feel micro, not elephant-like.

```
scala -cp /jvm/Thyme.jar
```

is all you need to do to run it in the REPL.

Now we need an implementation that actually works.  I'll write two.

First try:

```
def revStr(s: String): String = {
  val points = for (i <- s.indices if !s(i).isLowSurrogate) yield s.codePointAt(i)
  new String(points.toArray.reverse,0,points.length)
}
```

Not so hard.  Might be slow, though; probably lots of boxing there.  Let's try a faster version:

```
def reverseString(s: String): String = if (s.length < 2) s else {
  import java.lang.Character.{isLowSurrogate => lo, isHighSurrogate => hi}
  val chars = s.toCharArray
  var i = 0
  var j = s.length - 1
  var swapped = false
  while (i < j) {
    swapped = false
    val a = chars(i)
    val b = chars(j)
    if (lo(a) && j+1 < s.length && hi(chars(j+1))) {
      chars(j) = chars(j+1)
      chars(j+1) = a
      swapped = true
    }
    else chars(j) = a
    if (hi(b) && i > 0 && lo(chars(i-1))) {
      chars(i) = chars(i-1)
      chars(i-1) = b
      swapped = true
    }
    else chars(i) = b
    i += 1
    j -= 1
  }
  if (i==j) {
    val c = chars(i)
    if (lo(c) && j+1 < s.length && hi(chars(j+1))) {
      chars(j) = chars(j+1)
      chars(j+1) = c
    }
    else if (hi(c) && i > 0 && lo(chars(i-1))) {
      chars(i) = chars(i-1)
      chars(i-1) = c
    }
  }
  else if (!swapped && hi(chars(i)) && lo(chars(j))) {
    val temp = chars(i)
    chars(i) = chars(j)
    chars(j) = temp
  }
  new String(chars)
}
```

Ouch.  This is written for speed not ease of use, but ouch.

Anyway, let's test these out.  I'm not doing full warmups here, but we'll get an idea:

```
scala> val th = new ichi.bench.Thyme
th: ichi.bench.Thyme = ichi.bench.Thyme@174580e6

scala> val testString = "This is a \ud800\udc00 test!"
testString: String = This is a  test!

scala> val wrong = th.pbench{ testString.reverse }
Benchmark (327660 calls in 115.2 ms)
  Time:    164.8 ns   95% CI 157.4 ns - 172.3 ns   (n=19)
  Garbage: 97.66 ns   (n=2 sweeps measured)
wrong: String = !tset ?? a si sihT

scala> val slow = th.pbench{ revStr(testString) }
Benchmark (163820 calls in 467.2 ms)
  Time:    749.0 ns   95% CI 742.5 ns - 755.5 ns   (n=18)
  Garbage: 2.112 us   (n=2 sweeps measured)
slow: String = !tset  a si sihT

scala> val fast = th.pbench{ reverseString(testString) }
Benchmark (327660 calls in 36.32 ms)
  Time:    58.19 ns   95% CI 58.10 ns - 58.27 ns   (n=18)
  Garbage: 12.21 ns   (n=1 sweeps measured)
fast: String = !tset  a si sihT

scala> val compare = th.pbenchOff(){revStr(testString)}{reverseString(testString)}
Benchmark comparison (in 430.7 ms)
Significantly different (p ~= 0)
  Time ratio:    0.09495   95% CI 0.08061 - 0.10928   (n=20)
    First     777.9 ns   95% CI 756.0 ns - 799.8 ns
    Second    73.86 ns   95% CI 62.90 ns - 84.81 ns
  Individual benchmarks not fully consistent with head-to-head (p ~= 0)
    First     742.9 ns   95% CI 742.0 ns - 743.9 ns
    Second    58.33 ns   95% CI 58.19 ns - 58.46 ns
compare: String = !tset  a si sihT
```

So, in conclusion, use at least a minimal microbenchmarking tool if you want to do microbenchmarks.

Also, code points are annoying, and direct array manipulations are fast.

Comment: REPL should have a command to invoke a benchmark tool of your choice. Or sbt, as easy as `test`. It gets blurry what belongs at the sbt prompt or repl's, but maybe repl's.